# Error on Provider Service in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-services

i'm really new on Angular 2. I want to do a very basic service so i du this:

**apitest.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ApiTest {
    log(msg:string){
        console.log(msg);
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

import { DashboardModule } from './dashboard/dashboard.module';
import { SidebarModule } from './sidebar/sidebar.module';
import { FooterModule } from './shared/footer/footer.module';
import { NavbarModule} from './shared/navbar/navbar.module';

import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

import {ApiTest} from './shared/apiTest/apitest.service';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [
        BrowserModule,
        DashboardModule,
        SidebarModule,
        NavbarModule,
        FooterModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([])
    ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent, DashboardComponent ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: LocationStrategy, 
            useClass: HashLocationStrategy
        }, ApiTest],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**calendario.component.ts:**

```
 import {ApiTest} from './../../shared/ApiTest/apitest.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'calendario',
    templateUrl: 'calendario.component.html'
})
    export class CalendarioComponent{
         constructor( private apitest:ApiTest) {}
        obtenerDatos() {
            this.apitest.log("Hola desde servicio");
        }
    }
```

I got this error:
**EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for ApiTest**

If i change my component decorator to:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'calendario',
    templateUrl: 'calendario.component.html',
    providers: [ApiTest]
})
```

It works.

But... i learn that i cant declare my service on @NgModule and this service can be available on any component that i want! I based my answer on [the official Angular 2 Docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html)

I'm doing something wrong?
Thanks!

**[UPDATE 1]**

The calendarioComponent is inside another module, dashboardModule.

**dashboard.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthModule } from '../auth.module';
import {ApiTest} from './../shared/apiTest/apitest.service';
import { MODULE_COMPONENTS, MODULE_ROUTES } from './dashboard.routes';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(MODULE_ROUTES),
        AuthModule
    ],
    declarations: [ MODULE_COMPONENTS ],
    providers: [ApiTest]
})

export class DashboardModule{

}
```

As you can see, i added here the service import and provider, but **still give me the same error.**

Comment: Is your `CalendarioComponent` in a different module than `AppModule`?

Comment: mmm.. yes... i was thinking that if i put this on the root module its gonna be available for all modules, even... i'm wrong, right?

Comment: I added it to the module and still have the same error. i will update my text.

Comment: I update it my friend @Bwolfing

Comment: What version of angular you are using?

Comment: According with my packages.json, "@angular/common": "~2.2.2" @user3615920

Comment: Do you see my update @Bwolfing ?

Comment: @Prateik can you help me my friend? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... i found the solution. But this solution is very strange. I put my service file next to the module in the same folder where i inject my service and now works.

Before my Service was:

```
//calendario.component.ts
import {ApiTest} from './../../shared/ApiTest/apitest.service';
```

Now:

```
import {UserService} from '../apitest.service';
```

Before on my module:

```
import {ApiTest} from './../shared/apiTest/apitest.service';
```

Now:

```
import {UserService} from './apitest.service';
```

Maybe this will help to something else.

But i would like to know why???